# Avoid prompting Windows dialog credentials box

Tags: web-services, delphi, delphi-xe

I have a webservice and everytime I use the webservice I need to put username and password, but even if I save the login credentials, next time I open the webservice the credential box still continues to appear with the credentials inserted. But I don't want to see neither the dialog box, how should I do this?

I've already tried to see the windows credentials and I see them but the dialog still appears.

Comment: Which web service framework for Delphi are you using? Do you know which HTTP authentication method is being used?

Comment: I don't see anything about Delphi in this question.  If you can find the developer, they can ask a programming question here, of course.  I'd start there.  If your code isn't working the way you would like it's important that we can see that code to determine where it needs to be changed.

Comment: I don't see anything related to programming or Delphi. Voting to close as *Unclear* until you edit to add a specific programming question.